# Host name does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer, but it's a perfect match

Tags: ssl, docker, https, httpclient, self-signed

I have two servers that need to speak with each other using HTTPS.

Let's call them 'server' and 'client' in this case where 'client is making an https call to 'server'.

In production the server will have a valid CA certificate but while testing we will use a self-signed certificate.

As I understand it this is what we have to do:

1. create the certificate
2. add it to the keystore on server
3. add it to the trusted cacerts keystore on client (so that it will accept this self-signed cert when trying to make https calls)

this is all done, but when making the call I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'docker-abc-123' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=docker-abc-123, OU=unit, O=org, L=city, ST=area, C=xx)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:465) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:395) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) [httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:91) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:568) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
... 10 more
```

Even though the host name exactly matches the "Common Name" in the certificate. What can possibly cause this? Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is a Subject Alternative Names extension in the certificate, the common name is ignored, and the SAN must include a matching identifier for your host.

Comment: I just found the same thing and came back to write it, just to find your answer, hehe. We only have alternative names there, but not the actual CN there. I will try it and mark as correct when I've confirmed it solved the problem. (more info here: http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName)