# Host name does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer after library change

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, hystrix

After updating our project dependencies from apache *HttpClient 4.5.10 to 4.5.11* we keep getting this error in our local environment.

We use hystrix, so the connection itself uses *HttpAsyncClient (4.1.2).*

Production environments work fine after the update, so I guess there is a problem with our certificate that somehow does not pop up when using 4.5.10 for the ssl context configuration.

Does anyone have any idea what might be missing in the cert?

```
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'domain' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=domain, O=Something, ST=Some-State, C=NL)
        at org.apache.http.nio.conn.ssl.SSLIOSessionStrategy.verifySession(SSLIOSessionStrategy.java:209)
        at org.apache.http.nio.conn.ssl.SSLIOSessionStrategy$1.verify(SSLIOSessionStrategy.java:188)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:354)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:503)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
```

(I already checked this, and does not seem to match the problem)

[Host name does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer, but it's a perfect match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533325/host-name-does-not-match-the-certificate-subject-provided-by-the-peer-but-its)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was not the domain itself, but that it was a private domain and *DefaultHostnameVerifier* assumes it is an ICANN domain. Modifying the hostname verifier fixes it.

It was triggered by the change from 4.5.10 to 4.5.11 because of this commit: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/commit/858946348f5d34f9a8b4caf3c5f054721e647983#diff-842a4260950ada415839175b42257751

It actually corrects a verification problem, but the error is not exactly clear, so I hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: Cheers for this. How did you go about modifying the DefaultHostNameVerifier?

Answer (score 0):

The issue described above is fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-2047

Change the version to 4.5.12